# MySQL to group unique items across multiple columns with COUNTs for each?

Tags: php, mysql, e-commerce

firstly I know this is MySQL and I know I should be using MySQLi... so forgive me for that ...

I've been racking my brain all day over this, I am sure it SHOULD be simple. I have a table of products, and columns within the table for each product like colour, material, size, etc

I want to create a sidebar/filter when displaying results, so a user can filter the results to say just show "red" products, or just metal products etc etc.

I have got the mysql/php working to do this dynamically but I cannot for the life of me work out how to use COUNT within this to also show the number of each.

What I want is if you click a category and 10 products are within that category, the statement will create a dynamic filter based on all the various attributes (columns) from those 10 products (only showing unique) as so:

```
Colour:
Red (2)
Yellow (4)
Pink (1)
Blue (1)
Green (2)

Material:
China (3)
Paper (2)
Metal (5)
```

Code I have that works but doesn't have the count for each:

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT colour) FROM $table_products_description WHERE products_id IN (".$ids.")) as Colour, 
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT material) FROM $table_products_description WHERE products_id IN (".$ids.")) as Material");

foreach(mysql_fetch_assoc($sql) as $key=>$value)
{
    $html.='<h3>'.$key.'</h3>';
    $subvals=explode(",",$value);
    foreach($subvals as $subval)
    {
        $html.='<p>'.$subval.'</p>';
    }
}
```

Where $ids is an array of product ids for any given category or search result.

That displays this result which is nice, but has no counts by each:

```
**Colour**
Red
White
Blue
Green
Yellow
Black
Orange

**Material**
Fine Bone China
Ceramic
Cast Iron
Porcelain
```

I can get it to work nicely with just 1 column, using totally different statement as below, but how can I expand this to multiple columns?

```
select group_concat( concat( colour,'(',qty,')') separator ', ') Colour
from (
  select colour, count(*) qty
  from $table_product_description
  group by colour
) s
```

The above displays the values AND the counts for each but I can't get the above to work across lots of columns no matter what I try.. any ideas?

```
**Colour**
Red (3)
White (1)
Blue (2)
Green (1)
Yellow (1)
Black (1)
Orange (1)
```

So to summarize I need to select all unique values from multiple columns within a single table and then output all the resulting values with the total counts for each.

Any help massively appreciated!

Comment: If it was me, unless the data set was vast, I'd just return the entire thing and handle the filtering in application level code.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I know I could run 12 queries (or however many columns I want to use in the filter) or go through and count each item after in a totally separate statement, but I thought it'd be so neat to do it all in one statement, and I've come so close it hurts lol... I can make it work with just 1 column but can't get it to work with lots...

Comment: Here's an example of a website that the implements filtering in the way I suggest. It's a little glitchy, but hopefully you can get the idea. http://www.charlescarey.co.uk/works.php. The Kiva website is probably a more elegant implementation (although that probably does use asynchronous selects)

Comment: Hi, the thing is this doesn;t do much more than I already have in the actual sidebar information , its just a list like "portraiture, still-life" etc, they don't actually have a product count next to each option... it's nice how the actual filtering works when you click them BUT that's not what I'm worried about (yet) it's actually displaying the information in the side filter itself!

Comment: OK, but still,there's only one query here. That query goes off and grabs all the images and their associated 'themes' and 'media' (in this example). Then that's spat out into an array. That array is then parsed in order to arrive at a list of unique 'media' and unique 'themes'.

Comment: OK so could you give me an idea of code or pseudo code to do this? You are saying I should just select everything stick it into an array and then count the unique colors, sizes etc from the array rather than trying to do it all in the sql statement is that right? I should say the product table will eventually have 10,000 or so products so not small, so is it more efficient doing it in the sql statement or in arrays in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot aggregate (count) two different things in one row. This query...

```
SELECT 'Colour' AS category, colour AS value, count(*) AS qty
FROM $table_product_description
WHERE products_id IN($ids)
GROUP BY colour
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Material' AS category, material AS value, count(*) as qty
FROM $table_product_description
WHERE products_id IN($ids)
GROUP BY material
```

...will give you sth like this:

```
category | value | qty
Colour   | red   | 5
Colour   | blue  | 3
Material | metal | 2
Material | paper | 6
```

If you want to play with `group_concat()` you may wrap this query into:

```
SELECT a.category, group_concat( concat( a.value,'(',a.qty,')') separator ', ') AS list
FROM (
    ...above query...
) AS a
GROUP BY a.category
```

**Data access**

`mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)` returns one row each time it's called or false if there's nothing (more) to fetch.
It's usually done with `while()` loop like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    //For combined query $row in each iteration becomes:
    // 1: ['category' => 'Colour', 'list' => 'red(5), blue(3)']
    // 2: ['category' => 'Material', 'list' => 'metal(2),...']
}
```

Comment: Hi this seems to work! Just had to get my head around how to extract the data to display it and I think I'm getting there so thanks!

Comment: @BenM I didn't notice data access problem - added some explanation.

Comment: Hi thanks for the update, yes I am now using a while loop instead of the foreach as $key=>$value I had previously, all working great now and I have accepted this as the answer. Thank you! (I cannot up vote yet though!)

Comment: Sorry to bother again, but if I drop the group_concat stuff and just use the original query you sent, how do I then access the "category" name just a single time? At the moment if I do a loop it lists "Colour" above each colour for example? I thought withut group_concat it makes it easier to use the data when I post it etc (without having the (qty) as part of the value)

Comment: What I mean is 
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
 $html.='<h3>'.$row['category'].'</h3>';
 $html.=$row['value']." (".$row['qty'].")";
} 

returns
Colour
Red
Colour
Blue

etc, how can I access $row['category'] a single time for the title, wihtout it being inside the loop? Thanks!

Comment: There's no golden rule for handling nested data structures, but you should strive for obtaining plain `$data` first and then use it in response view context (even if it results in having moore loops). In your query loop you could either `explode()` conacatenated strings or build nested structure based on row values for example (simplified for one-liner): `$data[$row['category']][] = ['value' => $row['value'], 'qty' => $row['qty']];`. Now you can pass this `$data` into html+php template (file) where you build your html. Maybe in future you would like to pass it to javascropt in *json* format.

Comment: @BenM: Forgot to call. Btw. `$data` from example need nested loop to be  extracted into html, but its easier to display header/category line (outer loop) and its contents (inner loop).

Comment: Hi @shudder , I've been trying what you say but I really can't get this to work still, I am not sure in your last comment what you meant quite, could you give me a real-world example on how to do the nested loops to get category and it's values then next category and its values and so on? Thanks so much

Comment: @BenM: Maybe [this example](http://pastebin.com/zJSRhC4U) will help. I use diffrent syntax in template files - well I use templating engine that translates meta-code into this "phtml"). It's a matter of preference actually - separation is what matters here.

Comment: Yes @shudder that is brilliant, all working now thanks so much for your patience!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `group by`

```
"select 
 (
   select color,
     count(*) as rowcount 
   from $table_products_description 
   where products_id 
   in ($ids) 
   group by color
 ) as Color,
 (
   select material, 
     count(*) as rowcount 
   from $table_products_description 
   where products_id 
   in ($ids) 
   group by material
 ) as Material"
```

Comment: Hi, this looks like it SHOULD work and is very similar to what I've tried today but it doesn't seem to work, it just doesn't return anything at all, not even an error... any idea why that might be?